# NDK configuration on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to use andengine in my application so I downloaded ndk and added its path to local.properties but when I compile the following error appears

Execution failed for task ':libs:AndroidEngine:compileReleaseNdk'.> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\recai\Downloads\ndk\ndk-build.cmd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified